# Use sed to match end of line NOT preceded immediately by a certain character

Tags: regex, sed

I have a set of lines followed by '\' I want to print up to the line not containing the '\' character at the end of the line. Note that xx# yy# change per file and to be re-usable, I want my script to print lines from match1 to '\' end of line.

```
match1 xx1 xx1 xx1 xx1 \
yy1 yy1 yy1 yy1 \
zz\<1\> zz1 zz1 zz1 
xx2 xx2 xx2 xx2 \
...
```

output should be:

```
match1 xx1 xx1 xx1 xx1 \
yy1 yy1 yy1 yy1 \
zz\<1\> zz1 zz1 zz1
```

My best effort came up with:

```
sed -n '/match1/,/\\/p' file
```

but does not work.
Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command will do what you want:

```
sed -n '/match1/,/[^\\]$/p' file
```

Using the `^` at the start of a character class negates the match.

---

Following to [glenn jackman's great comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570303/use-sed-to-match-end-of-line-not-preceded-immediately-by-a-certain-character/31570386?noredirect=1#comment51096083_31570386) the above solution has a little problem. Since `[^\\]` requires at least one character it would not work if the first line which not ends with a \ is an empty line. Let me add his solution which should be the preferred one:

```
sed -n '/match1/,/\(^\|[^\\]\)$/p' file
```

Comment: That works.  Thank you.  I'll accept this answer in 5 min. when I am able.

Comment: I would suggest `'/match1/,/\(^\|[^\\]\)$/p'` to allow the case where the line not ending with a slash is an empty line.